# MDA-8086 8*8 Dot matrix display code segment explaination

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dot-matrix

I have a code that display 'A' in the dot matrix display of MDA-8086. Here is it:

```
ORG 1000H
MOV AL, 10000000B       ;Activate Signal
OUT 1EH, AL             ;Writing Activate signal to  Control Register
MOV AL, 11111111B       ;Off Signal
OUT 18H, AL             ;Writing off signal to Port A
L1: MOV SI, OFFSET FONT ;Assigning source address to Memory address/                            ;offset of FONT Variable
    MOV AH, 00000001B
L2: MOV AL, BYTE PTR CS:[SI]
    OUT 1AH, AL
    MOV AL, AH
    OUT 1CH, AL
    CALL TIMER
    INC SI
    CLC
    ROL AH, 1
    JNC L2
    JMP L1
    INT 3
TIMER: MOV CX, 300
TIMER1: NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        LOOP TIMER1
        RET
FONT: DB 11111111B
      DB 11001001B
      DB 10110100B
      DB 10110110B
      DB 10110110B
      DB 10110110B
      DB 10000000B
      DB 11111111B
```

Now I don't get these lines; `MOV SI, OFFSET FONT` and `MOV AL, BYTE PTR CS:[SI]`. can anyone tell me what these lines do?
**Edit:**

I also want to know how `DB` is working in `FONT` and how each `DB` is evaluated.

Comment: `MOV SI, OFFSET FONT` puts the address of FONT in SI. `MOV AL, BYTE PTR CS:[SI]` moves the byte at CS:[SI] into the AL register.

Comment: You tag this `emu8086` but this doesn't look like it is for emu8086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I don't get these lines

16- and 32-bit code of x86 CPUs always use two numbers to specify the address of something stored in memory:

The segment and the offset.

The segment describes some region in memory.

The "real" address of some item in memory can be calculated by:

```
(address of the first byte of the segment) + offset
```

The `CS` register is normally read-only. It contains the segment which contains the instruction which is currently executed.

The `MOV SI, OFFSET FONT` instruction will now write the offset of the data following the `FONT:` label to the `SI` register.

The `MOV AL, BYTE PTR CS:[SI]` instruction will read one byte from the memory into the register `AL`. The byte is read from the following address:

```
(address of the first byte of the CS segment) + (value of register SI)
```

Because the `FONT:` label is in the same segment as the instruction itself (`CS`) and `SI` contains the offset of `FONT:` the address calculated this way is the address of the first byte of `FONT:`.

In other words: The instruction loads the first byte of `FONT:` into the register `AL`.

(When the instruction is called the second time the second byte of `FONT:` will be loaded because `SI` has been incremented.)

> I also want to know how DB is working ...

`DB` is not an instruction.

`DB` tells the assembler to write a byte with a certain value into the memory *instead* of an instruction.

So the following (non-sense) code:

```
mov ax, 1
db 10
mov ax, 2
```

... means that there shall be the byte with the value 10 between the two `mov` instructions.

> how DB is working in FONT

The 8 bytes (here not specified as decimal but as binary numbers) are stored at the memory location named `FONT:`.

Comment: So, the bytes written by `DB` are stored in code segment? And, I've seen very few elaborate answer like yours. So thanks.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: `db` emits a byte at the current position in the current section.  [Syntactically, it's just like any other instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513413/x86-asm-dd-being-used-as-an-instruction) (so you could call it a pseudo-instruction).  Remember that assembly language doesn't have "variables" or anything, it's just a language for conveniently describing which bytes you want where.  Labels let you get the assembler to calculate offsets and stuff, but still each line just makes the assembler emit some bytes into the output file.